# error "gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When I'm trying to execute gatsby, it generates temp-328932 file in .cache
temp-328932 file shouldn't be generate,
this is unusual behaviour
I'm not sure why this is happening.....

I'm facing some issues while I'm trying to execute gatsby...
I'm not sure what the problem is...
but this is what I got from console...

```
error "gatsby-source-graphql" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined


  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

  - From previous event:

  - api-runner-node.js:554 Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName
  /[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:554:9

 warning The gatsby-source-graphql plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need it?

 object
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -4078,
```

**What all I have tried...**

```
 gatsby clean
 gatsby develop
 removed node_modules
 removed cache
 removed package-lock.json
 npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli
 npm install -g gatsby-cli
 uninstalled node and re-installed
 uninstalled Visual studio and re-installed
```

Comment: It's a fresh installation? If not, provide your `gatsby-node.js` it seems that there's something odd there when Gatsby is trying to generate the nodes.

Comment: When I'm trying to execute gatsby, it generates temp-328932 file in .cache
temp-328932 file shouldn't be generate, this is unusual behaviour
I'm not sure why this is happening.....

Comment: Do you have anything inside `gatsby-node.js`? Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it also throws an error because of different Gatsby version.

suppose if you have installed Gatsby globally and when you take a clone of other project, there could be of two different version of Gatsby and this could throw unwanted error

1. uninstall Gatsby globally

   npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli
2. clone project in your machine
3. npm install